React Native Expo SQLiteProvider not working
It keeps giving me error of
None of these files exist:

appdatabase.db
app\assets\database\appdatabase.db

Below is my code
All file and path are correctly stated
import { SessionProvider } from "@/authentication/SessionProvider";
import { Slot } from "expo-router";
import { SQLiteProvider } from "expo-sqlite";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <SQLiteProvider
      databaseName="appdatabase.db"
      assetSource={{ assetId: require("./assets/database/appdatabase.db") }}
    >
      <SessionProvider>
        <Slot />
      </SessionProvider>
    </SQLiteProvider>
  );
}

I try change the name, reset the IDE...
